# How to know which version of angular/common to use to satisfy the dependencies?

Tags: angular, dependencies, pipeline

When I deployed my changes to the master branch, the pipeline failed. If I'm correct, the error indicates a conflict in the versions of @angular/common required by different dependencies in the project. The root project requires @angular/common@"^16.0.0", while ngrx-store-localstorage@16.1.0 requires a peer dependency of @angular/common@"^17.0.4".

Here is the error in the pipeline that failed during npm install:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: dim-angular@0.0.
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.4" from ngrx-store-localstorage@16.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ngrx-store-localstorage
npm ERR!   ngrx-store-localstorage@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: But do you see the same error in your local dev environment?

Comment: I cant replicate the same error in my local dev environment. I deleted node_modules and ran npm install, it didn't display the same error

Comment: delete also the package-lock.json

Comment: i dont know if it actually affects the build, but we don't have package-lock.json in the master branch

Comment: after deleting package-lock.json in my local dev environment. i get the same error

Comment: Update: I recreated the package-lock.json in my local dev environment and npm install was successful then push to master but the same issue persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must ensure that `npm install` works on your local machine. Often the problem comes from the fact that you use `^` to specify the version of your dependency, see more details about semantic versioning [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning).  In this case, you do not have much control over the exact version of dependency and their dependencies, and sometimes, the project breaks. I would recommend removing `^` to control exact versions manually, and running `npm outdated` from time to time, to see if you want to proceed with updates. Silent automatic updates may give you surprises, such as it worked yesterday, but stopped working today "for no reason".

Then, you should ensure that your deployment uses the same versions of all the dependencies. This is why the file `package-lock.json` exists. See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-lock-json) for more explanation. I recommend committing this file to your repository and running `npm ci` to install the dependencies, see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ci).

A similar approach should be applied to `yarn` package manager or others.

Comment: removing the "^" did worked to get the exact version of the dependency. thank you for your detailed explanation, much appreciated.